# Making groups (group_by) depending on the column value with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to make groups with dplyr depending on a condition. For example, if we have the following table:

```
A      B 
1      0
10     1
5      1
6      2
```

I would make groups when B = 0, another when B > 1, another when B > 2, and so on. The following approximation is wrong but maybe helps to understand:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(B > 0:2) %>% 
   summarize(Total = sum(A))
```

Comment: `B==0` or `B > 0`?

Comment: Thank you for posting the code that didn't work—that's helpful for knowing what your approach might be. (I guess comments now get rejected for starting with "+1")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rows can't belong to more than one group when using `group_by` with `dplyr`. You'd need to map over values and repeatedly do the filtering. Here's one way to do that

```
purrr::map_df(0:2, ~df %>% filter(B>.x) %>% summarize(b_greater_than=.x, Total=sum(A)))
#   b_greater_than Total
# 1              0    21
# 2              1     6
# 3              2     0
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but I thought that maybe was possible to do it directly without another function. Anyway, it works well.